# How to enable POST(webhooks) on express-session/passport app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, webhooks

My app returns 403(forbidden) when it receives webhooks from an external service.

I don't know which of the middelwares (express, or express-session, or express-validator, or passport) is blocking the webhooks (POSTs).

Must i enable it from passport or express-session config located on the **app.js**?

Here is my server setup:
**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var validator = require('express-validator');
var SQLiteStore = require('connect-sqlite3')(session);

var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'tknMngr', 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new SQLiteStore,
    cookie: { maxAge: 180*60*1000 }
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
require('./config/passport');
app.use(require('./routes/route'));
app.use(require('./routes'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
module.exports = app;
```

and this is my **route.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/webhook', function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).render('webhook', {data: res, title: 'IPN'});
  console.log('200.OK');
  res.end();
});
module.exports = router;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Simply by changing the order of `app.use(require('./routes/route'));` **before** the session setup (in **app.js** file), it works fine.

It seems that the order in which the `app.use(require (...));` is declared and the rest of the functions define the behavior of the application.

I hope to find some info about this "order" in the API/Doc of Express or Node.js.

I hope someone helps this info.

This's the right order:

```
app.use(require('./routes/route'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
require('./config/passport');
app.use(require('./routes'));
```